# Фильтрация массива объектов по конкретному свойству

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Необходима помощь в фильтрации массива объектов.

На входе имеем массив, который получаем в ответ на запрос к серверу, например:

```
let arr = [
  { id: 0, streetName: '30 лет Победы', streetId: 0, addressId: 0, building: '1', flat: '1' },
  { id: 2, streetName: '30 лет Победы', streetId: 0, addressId: 1, building: '1', flat: '2' },
  { id: 2, streetName: '30 лет Победы', streetId: 0, addressId: 2, building: '1', flat: '3' },
  { id: 1, streetName: 'Ленина', streetId: 1, addressId: 3, building: '15', flat: '7' },
  { id: 1, streetName: 'Ленина', streetId: 1, addressId: 4, building: '15', flat: '9' },
  { id: 1, streetName: 'Ленина', streetId: 1, addressId: 5, building: '15', flat: '10' },
  { id: 3, streetName: 'Советская', streetId: 2, addressId: 6, building: '40', flat: '2' },
  { id: 3, streetName: 'Советская', streetId: 2, addressId: 7, building: '40', flat: '7' },
  { id: 3, streetName: 'Советская', streetId: 2, addressId: 8, building: '40', flat: '9' },
  { id: 4, streetName: 'Мира', streetId: 3, addressId: 9, building: '5', flat: '3' },
  { id: 4, streetName: 'Мира', streetId: 3, addressId: 10, building: '5', flat: '4' },
  { id: 4, streetName: 'Мира', streetId: 3, addressId: 11, building: '5', flat: '5' },
];
```

Далее, я отрисовываю его на странице с помощью реакт

```
return (
  <div>
    {housingStock.map((hs, index) => {
      return <li key={`${hs}_${index}`}>{hs.streetName}</li>;
    })}
  </div>);
```

В итоге у меня выводится список с повторяющимися значениями из свойства streetName

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне необходимо отфильтровать массив так, чтобы если значение из свойства streetName, при его повторе отрисовывалось лишь один раз.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это правильно сделать.

Я понимаю, что необходимо пройтись по массиву, например, методом map, но что дальше делать никак не могу выразить в коде

Comment: А что делает вот этот кусочек кода `... key={${hs}_...`

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg добавляет атрибут key, это react syntax

Comment: @InDevX Я и хочу понять, к чему приведет этот маленький фрагмент `${hs}`. Разве это не будет выглядеть как `[object Object]_1`?

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg Вероятно это будет выглядеть так, но ключ должен быть уникальным - это главное, и поскольку индексы массива "уникальные" то и данный атрибут будет уникальный, а само значение роли не играет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать промежуточный объект `Set` для избавления от дубликатов (передав в конструктор массив названий улиц):

```
return (
  <ul>
    {[...new Set(housingStock.map(hs => hs.streetName))].map(
      sn => (<li key={sn}>{sn}</li>)
    )}
  </ul>
);
```

Насколько я понимаю реактъ, подклеивать числовой индекс к названию в значении `key` тут не нужно (потому что каждое название улицы в результате будет уникальным).

```js
let arr = [
  { id: 0, streetName: '30 лет Победы', streetId: 0, addressId: 0, building: '1', flat: '1' },
  { id: 2, streetName: '30 лет Победы', streetId: 0, addressId: 1, building: '1', flat: '2' },
  { id: 2, streetName: '30 лет Победы', streetId: 0, addressId: 2, building: '1', flat: '3' },
  { id: 1, streetName: 'Ленина', streetId: 1, addressId: 3, building: '15', flat: '7' },
  { id: 1, streetName: 'Ленина', streetId: 1, addressId: 4, building: '15', flat: '9' },
  { id: 1, streetName: 'Ленина', streetId: 1, addressId: 5, building: '15', flat: '10' },
  { id: 3, streetName: 'Советская', streetId: 2, addressId: 6, building: '40', flat: '2' },
  { id: 3, streetName: 'Советская', streetId: 2, addressId: 7, building: '40', flat: '7' },
  { id: 3, streetName: 'Советская', streetId: 2, addressId: 8, building: '40', flat: '9' },
  { id: 4, streetName: 'Мира', streetId: 3, addressId: 9, building: '5', flat: '3' },
  { id: 4, streetName: 'Мира', streetId: 3, addressId: 10, building: '5', flat: '4' },
  { id: 4, streetName: 'Мира', streetId: 3, addressId: 11, building: '5', flat: '5' },
];

const result = [...new Set(arr.map(hs => hs.streetName))];
console.log(result);

const e = React.createElement;
ReactDOM.render(
  e('ul', null,
    ...[...new Set(arr.map(hs => hs.streetName))].map(
      sn => e('li', { key: sn }, sn)
    )
  ),
  document.getElementById('')
);
```

```html
<div id=""><div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, этот способ помог

Answer (score 2):

```js
let arr = [
  { id: 0, streetName: '30 лет Победы', streetId: 0, addressId: 0, building: '1', flat: '1' },
  { id: 2, streetName: '30 лет Победы', streetId: 0, addressId: 1, building: '1', flat: '2' },
  { id: 2, streetName: '30 лет Победы', streetId: 0, addressId: 2, building: '1', flat: '3' },
  { id: 1, streetName: 'Ленина', streetId: 1, addressId: 3, building: '15', flat: '7' },
  { id: 1, streetName: 'Ленина', streetId: 1, addressId: 4, building: '15', flat: '9' },
  { id: 1, streetName: 'Ленина', streetId: 1, addressId: 5, building: '15', flat: '10' },
  { id: 3, streetName: 'Советская', streetId: 2, addressId: 6, building: '40', flat: '2' },
  { id: 3, streetName: 'Советская', streetId: 2, addressId: 7, building: '40', flat: '7' },
  { id: 3, streetName: 'Советская', streetId: 2, addressId: 8, building: '40', flat: '9' },
  { id: 4, streetName: 'Мира', streetId: 3, addressId: 9, building: '5', flat: '3' },
  { id: 4, streetName: 'Мира', streetId: 3, addressId: 10, building: '5', flat: '4' },
  { id: 4, streetName: 'Мира', streetId: 3, addressId: 11, building: '5', flat: '5' },
];

console.log(
arr.reduce((arr, el) => 
  ((arr.find(({streetName}) => el.streetName == streetName) || arr.push(el)), arr)
, [])
)
```